# Select [sth] with at least two [activity] with gap time of at least 24 hours in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, select

Got a final project of developing a pandemic outbreak monitoring system database. other stuff I figured out pretty much, but this select statement I have no idea how to write:

List the phone numbers of all citizens who did two viral tests with the time window from
2021-10-03 00:00 to 2021-10-05 00:00. The two viral tests must have a gap time of at least 24 hours (at least 24 hours apart).

this is part of my diagram and is prob all that's needed for this particular question (ignore the doctor chart prob not needed here)

[image]

I was initially thinking maybe for each SSN count how many test IDs there are and then check if bigger than 2, but how's the 24 hr time gonna be calculated... and if 3 tests with like 20 hrs and 8 hrs in between then first and third is more than 24... anyways, u can hopefully see where I'm headed and how wrong I'm thinking lol. any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: if they have three tests, each separated by 13 hours, are they included or excluded?

Comment: @ysth most likely included

Comment: Why not absorb the Patient table into the Test Table by simply adding the Social Security Number  as a foreign key field in Test?

Comment: @toonice yeah good point. the patient table had more variables b4 I must have missed ur point. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be this one:

```
SELECT a.ssn, MAX(a.phone) phone
FROM citizens a
JOIN patients b ON a.ssn = b.ssn
JOIN test c ON b.test_id = c.test_id
WHERE c.test_time BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00'
GROUP BY a.ssn
HAVING TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, MIN(c.test_time), MAX(c.test_time)) >= 24
```

Sample data tested

```
CREATE TABLE citizens (
  ssn VARCHAR(20),
  phone VARCHAR(20)
);
CREATE TABLE patients (
  ssn VARCHAR(20),
  test_id INT
);
CREATE TABLE test (
  test_id INT,
  test_time DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO citizens VALUES ( 'A', '123' ), ( 'B', '456' ), ( 'C', '789' );
INSERT INTO patients VALUES ( 'A', 1 ), ( 'A', 2 ), ( 'A', 3 );
INSERT INTO patients VALUES ( 'B', 4 ), ( 'B', 5 ), ( 'B', 6 );
INSERT INTO patients VALUES ( 'C', 7 );

INSERT INTO test VALUES 
( 1, '2021-10-03 10:00:00' ),
( 2, '2021-10-03 20:00:00' ),
( 3, '2021-10-04 12:00:00' ),
( 4, '2021-10-03 10:00:00' ),
( 5, '2021-10-03 12:00:00' ),
( 6, '2021-10-03 19:00:00' ),
( 7, '2021-10-03 10:00:00' );
```

Comment: looks great, thanks mate :) but can i ask what the max(a.phone) is? first time I've seen it so idk what it does lol

Comment: @CurryFlurry because `a.phone` is not in the `GROUP BY` clause, it has to aggregate the such columns to comply with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: @ProGu ssn it a primary key, so phone is a functionally dependent column and can be included without the MAX as of mysql 5.7.5 (though not yet in mariadb)

Comment: @toonice in my sample data, it's only 9 hours gap for `B`, not satisfying the condition for 24 hours https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47149dc7122887daee455132d38fecdd

Comment: Yes, which means that it should NOT be listed as only gaps greater than (or equal to) 24 hours should be.

Comment: So it's true it is not listed. The result set in db fiddle is only `A`. I'm not quite understand what is the problem?

Comment: I have just tested your statements again in `MySQL 8.0 Command Line Client`.  It returns ( 'B', '456' ).  Examining the data you have supplied reveals that there is NO chronologically consecutive pair of records for a `Citizen` that are more than 24 hours apart, therefore no results should be returned.

Comment: No point to argue any more. I use MySQL8 command line too.

Comment: @toonice can you demonstrate the problem you are seeing with a dbfiddle link?

Comment: The discrepancy was caused by a typo.  My apologies for the confusion.  I would remove my downvote, but it has been more than 18 hours.  I have deleted the comment to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, my answer is based upon the assumption that `Patient` should be absorbed into `Test` as per my comment from earlier.  I can update my Answer to include code for the listed table structure either as well or instead upon request.

(The following answer versions have been tested against the following test data)

### Answer Query (If a third test may occur between two that are at least 24 hours apart)

I have started by inner joining two copies of `Test` to themselves and then inner joining the results to `Citizen` so that for each `Citizen` all records where there is at least 24 hours between them are returned, irrespective of if a third record occurs in between them that is less than 24 hours distant from them.

Each record generated shall contain the Test Times (and Test ID's) for that match.  I have selected theme here to demonstrate how they may be used to inform the user and as a suggestion for expansion possibilities for the statement (should the user wish to expand it).

There should be no duplicate records.

```
SELECT Citizen.ssn AS 'Social Security Number',
       Citizen.phone_number AS 'Phone Number',
       greater_than_first_table.test_id AS 'First Test ID',
       greater_than_first_table.test_time AS 'First Test Time',
       greater_than_second_table.test_id AS 'Second Test ID',
       greater_than_second_table.test_time AS 'Second Test Time'
FROM       Test AS greater_than_first_table
INNER JOIN Test AS greater_than_second_table ON greater_than_first_table.ssn = greater_than_second_table.ssn AND
                                                TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR,
                                                               greater_than_first_table.test_time,
                                                               greater_than_second_table.test_time ) >= 24
INNER JOIN Citizen ON greater_than_first_table.ssn = Citizen.ssn
WHERE greater_than_first_table.test_time  BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00' AND
      greater_than_second_table.test_time BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00';
```

### Answer  Query (As above, but with just the phone numbers)

If the user is only interested in the phone numbers from the above, then the following can be used.

`GROUP BY` is used to eliminate duplicate results.

```
SELECT Citizen.phone_number AS 'Phone Number'
FROM       Test AS greater_than_first_table
INNER JOIN Test AS greater_than_second_table ON greater_than_first_table.ssn = greater_than_second_table.ssn AND
                                                TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR,
                                                               greater_than_first_table.test_time,
                                                               greater_than_second_table.test_time ) >= 24
INNER JOIN Citizen ON greater_than_first_table.ssn = Citizen.ssn
WHERE greater_than_first_table.test_time  BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00' AND
      greater_than_second_table.test_time BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00'
GROUP BY Citizen.ssn;
```

### Answer Query (If at least 24 hours before the next test)

The following is a modified version of the first of the bove statements that eliminates results where a third value occurs less than 24 hours after the first one, i.e. it only lists records where there is 24 hours or more before the next chronologically occurring test.

A subquery is used to generate those records of two tests occurring less than 24 hours apart for a `Citizen`.  A `LEFT JOIN` is then performed on between the records that may contain a pair of times less than 24 hours apart that were generated by the main query's first `INNER JOIN` (the `LEFT` table) and the ones from the subquery (the `RIGHT` table).  The final `WHERE` clause in the main query eliminates those records from its results identified by the subquery.

```
SELECT Citizen.ssn AS 'Social Security Number',
       Citizen.phone_number AS 'Phone Number',
       greater_than_first_table.test_id AS 'First Test ID',
       greater_than_first_table.test_time AS 'First Test Time',
       greater_than_second_table.test_id AS 'Second Test ID',
       greater_than_second_table.test_time AS 'Second Test Time'
FROM       Test AS greater_than_first_table
INNER JOIN Test AS greater_than_second_table ON greater_than_first_table.ssn = greater_than_second_table.ssn AND
                                                TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR,
                                                               greater_than_first_table.test_time,
                                                               greater_than_second_table.test_time ) >= 24
INNER JOIN Citizen ON greater_than_first_table.ssn = Citizen.ssn
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT less_than_first_table.ssn       AS less_than_ssn,
           less_than_first_table.test_time AS less_than_test_time
    FROM       Test AS less_than_first_table
    INNER JOIN Test AS less_than_second_table ON less_than_first_table.ssn = less_than_second_table.ssn AND
                                                 TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR,
                                                                less_than_first_table.test_time,
                                                                less_than_second_table.test_time ) > 0 AND
                                                 TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR,
                                                                less_than_first_table.test_time,
                                                                less_than_second_table.test_time ) < 24

    WHERE less_than_first_table.test_time  BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00' AND
          less_than_second_table.test_time BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00'
) AS less_than_table ON greater_than_first_table.ssn = less_than_table.less_than_ssn AND
                        greater_than_first_table.test_time = less_than_table.less_than_test_time
WHERE greater_than_first_table.test_time  BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00' AND
      greater_than_second_table.test_time BETWEEN '2021-10-03 00:00:00' AND '2021-10-05 00:00:00' AND
      less_than_table.less_than_ssn IS NULL;
```

### Test Data Statements

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Citizen;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Test;

CREATE TABLE Citizen
(
    ssn           VARCHAR( 50 )   NOT NULL,
    phone_number  VARCHAR( 50 )   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT pkc_citizen              PRIMARY KEY ( ssn ),
    CONSTRAINT unc_citizen_phone_number UNIQUE      ( phone_number )
);

CREATE TABLE Test
(
    test_id     INT            NOT NULL   AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ssn         VARCHAR( 50 )  NOT NULL,
    test_time      DATETIME,
    CONSTRAINT pkc_test           PRIMARY KEY( test_id ),
    CONSTRAINT fkc_test_citizen   FOREIGN KEY ( ssn ) REFERENCES Citizen( ssn )
);

INSERT INTO Citizen VALUES ( 'THX-1138', '555-555-555' );
INSERT INTO Citizen VALUES ( 'TK4218',   '555-111-111' );
INSERT INTO Citizen VALUES ( 'R2-D2',    '555-222-222' );

INSERT INTO Test ( ssn, test_time ) VALUES ( 'THX-1138', '2021-10-02 22:34:51' );
INSERT INTO Test ( ssn, test_time ) VALUES ( 'THX-1138', '2021-10-03 09:00:00' );
INSERT INTO Test ( ssn, test_time ) VALUES ( 'THX-1138', '2021-10-03 10:00:00' );
INSERT INTO Test ( ssn, test_time ) VALUES ( 'THX-1138', '2021-10-04 11:34:51' );
INSERT INTO Test ( ssn, test_time ) VALUES ( 'TK4218',   '2021-10-03 10:34:51' );
INSERT INTO Test ( ssn, test_time ) VALUES ( 'TK4218',   '2021-10-04 11:34:51' );
```

Comment: this seems unnecessarily complex?  a left join would be needed if they wanted to exclude a case where they have more than two tests, none >= 24 hours apart, but where there are 24 hours between non-adjacent tests, but from the comments to the question they do *not* want to exclude that case; a simple group by and comparison of min and max times in a having clause is perfectly adequate

Comment: The way that the question is phrased is ambiguous, with the follow up comment indicating that the Questioner isn't certain which interpretation to choose.  I have updated my answer to cover both possibilities.